# Объявление функции при загрузке окна, необходимость аргументов

Tags: javascript, функции, загрузка

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    draw();
}

window.onload = draw;
```

Обе записи валидны, почему в первом случае нужны скобки (пустой список параметров), во втором  - без них работает. Какая тут у JS логика?

Comment: выдели о каких именно скобках идет речь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS подставляет ссылку на функцию, неважно каким образом она  определена - явно или  неявно. То есть в первом случае создается функция у которой нет названия и значение присваивается переменной, а во втором случае присвается название/ссылкка на функцию, которая уже была определена.